# Is there a private API for sending HCI command under iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi, bluetooth-hci

Is there a way to send HCI command under iOS (even using private API)?

Comment: Do you mean Bluetooth host/controller interface?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fast glance, I didn't find it (all I found higher level interfaces)

I checked two frameworks (you are welcome to double check this, because my Bluetooth knowledge is limited)

- /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
- /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth

And I found some references to it in BTServer:

- /usr/sbin/BTServer

As I understand this is a daemon which does all the work related to BT on iOS. However, it doesn't provide interfaces to internal functionality except through frameworks.